# ROW_NUMBER() equivalent in MySQL for inserting

Tags: mysql, sql, row-number

i'm trying to convert SQL scripts that was created in Microsoft SQL Server to run with a link sever to scripts that can be used in SQL Procedures, the script i'm on uses

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [FIELDS])
```

to create a primary key that isn't dependent on Auto Increment, when i try and save the code as a Procedure i get this error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY [FIELDS])' at line [LINENO]

obviously the error is saying that ROW_NUMBER OVER is not right cause i removed the OVER bit and got an error saying that ROW_NUMBER was undefined

everywhere i search i get nothing but people asking this question for SELECT statement, not INSERT statements and the answers most of the time are just about either getting the number of rows or getting the last id inserted, so what i can i use to create the same data that ROW_NUMBER() would in Microsoft Server

Comment: It is saying that the `OVER` function has invalid arguments.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: OVER isn't in MySQL anyway, i checked by searching for it in Google and only got links to MSDN, even if the argument was right it would probably give either the same message as ROW_NUMBER or a Syntax Error between the 2 functions......and yes the script works in Microsoft SQL Server cause i ran it in that, since it only uses the Link Server i'm making the script run better by moving it from using a link server to actually being used in the server itself

Comment: i'm trying to INSERT the row number into a table, i can't use INSERT INTO [TABLE] VALUES(@rank+1) cause that'll just get me 1 every time which is not allowed for a primary key and i've tried @row += 1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no `ROW_NUMBER()` equivalent in MySQL but you can still simulate it by creating a simple variable which holds a value an increment it every row.

Example:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT   @rank := @rank+1 AS rank, fruit, amount
FROM     sales
ORDER BY amount DESC;
```

- [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b14f/2)

Comment: It's not returning row numbers like 1,2,3... . It's returning 1,2,9,11... That's not what I want