# mysql sort table and get row position mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following table structure for a table Player

```
Table Player {  
Long playerID;  
Long points;  
Long rank;  
}
```

Assuming that the playerID and the points have valid values, can I update the rank for all the players based on the number of points in a single query? If two people have the same number of points, they should tie for the rank.

**UPDATE:**

I'm using hibernate using the query suggested as a native query. Hibernate does not like using variables, especially the ':'. Does anyone know of any workarounds? Either by not using variables or working around hibernate's limitation in this case by using HQL?

Comment: this serves your purpose http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963818/row-number-equivalent-in-mysql-for-inserting

Answer (score 0):

```
select  @a:=@a+1 position,
      id, 
      sum(item_1+item_2+item_3) as item_sum 
 from yourtable , (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a
 group by id 
 order by item_sum desc;
```

you can also try this

```
SET @position=0;
SELECT   @position:= @position+1 AS position,   
          id, 
          sum(item_1+item_2+item_3) as item_sum 
     from yourtable
     group by id 
     order by item_sum desc;
```

or try this one.......

```
SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS position, item_sum , id
FROM (
  select 
      id, 
      sum(item_1+item_2+item_3) as item_sum 
 from yourtable 
 group by id 
 order by item_sum desc
) t1, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2;
```

Comment: The positions are not in order

Comment: what happens with the second query then?

Comment: @DinupKandel: You shouldn't copy someone's answer in the same question at least!

Comment: I just tried the second query, it has the same results. The positions are not in order

Comment: @sarwar026 i havent copied you answer. see the time gap between the answer you have given and mine. you might be mistaken.

Comment: @DinupKandel: I want to mean your second query not the first one.

Comment: @user2310422 this might be because you have done order by `item_sum`

Comment: That's the thing, I want to order them by item_sum THEN get their position

Comment: @sarwar026 i took the hints from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963818/row-number-equivalent-in-mysql-for-inserting . but i have not copied your answer. you too might have seen the answer from there too.

Comment: That's the thing, I want to order them by item_sum THEN get their position

Comment: @sarwar026 at the end i can say you are not the only one who writes query like this...

Comment: This is not a place to fight. You guys acts like a kid

Comment: @RajeevRanjan: if you see the comments of question, You will see I first post the original question and then when I see the answer this user post didn't work well, then I guess, I can post the answer here too. You understand my point? Thanks

Comment: This is not a place to fight. You guys acts like a kid

Comment: @RajeevRanjan you too join the group. I know the first sql  trick by myself as i have implemented this before. and there is no wrong on writing this answer as it cause the knowledge to share.

Comment: At least make some sense

Comment: @user2310422 i will modify my answer just check to see if it is correct.

Comment: @user2310422 do you get through you problem?

Answer (score 0):

// increment num by one for each result row @num:=@num+1 with aliasname position and define it initially with 0,or by what to want to be..

```
select @num:=@num+1 position,
  id, 
  sum(item_1+item_2+item_3) as item_sum 
  from yourtable,(SELECT @num:=0) r
group by id 
order by item_sum desc;
```