# Incrementing counter on each duplicate in column

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a table:

```
id | value
1  | -
1  | a
2  | b
1  | c
3  | d
2  | e
```

then I need a counter column which begins from 1 for every different value in the id column

Desired select result:

```
id | value | counter
1  | -     | 1
1  | a     | 2
2  | b     | 1
1  | c     | 3
3  | d     | 1
2  | e     | 2
```

All I found was for counting the number of duplicates etc., but not for an incrementing counter on each duplicate of a specific column...?

Comment: This is do-able with some hacks in MySQL, but IMO you should consider doing it in the app instead.

Comment: @Vatev Actually it's some query in the init file configured in the my.cnf to initialize a memory table for quicker access; I can't really use a separate script for that?

Comment: value of id is static or can add new id??

Comment: @RonaldAlexanderKailola the id is static (that memory table is completely regenerated at every change; the cron runs once a day)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not care about ordering, only about corresponding row number, use variables like this:

```
SELECT 
  t.*, 
  @i:=IF(id=@id, @i+1, 1) AS num, 
  @id:=id 
FROM 
  t 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i:=0, @id:=0) AS init 
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: This will work, yes - but `FULL SACN` is guaranteed on table without indexing. Should be faster than `JOIN`, however

Comment: Taking less than a second on a big table, it's perfect :-)

Comment: And if you care about ordering you can wrap this in another SELECT and order by whatever.

Comment: @Vatev yup, that's what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to accomplish is called **RANKING** . Unfortunately MySQL doesnot have ranking functions like in SQL Server `ROW_NUMBER()` , `DENSE_RANK()` etc..

You can try below query for MySQL

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Value, count(*) as Counter 
FROM tableName t
JOIN tableName b ON t.ID = b.ID AND t.Value >= b.Value
GROUP BY t.ID, t.Value
```

[**SQL Fiddle DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02228/1)

Comment: Nice, just one little problem: It's not yet finished after 5 minutes on a 20k rows table; do you have something a bit faster eventually?

Comment: Sorry , I work on SQL Server , don't have much knowledge of MySQL :(

Comment: Without proper indexing this _will be slow_ because of how `JOIN` works with specified condition

Comment: BTW have done indexing on columns.. ? If not , see doing it as Indexing considerably improves performance when Joins are used

Comment: This will be slow regardless, I'm afraid. It just doesn't scale so well.

Comment: better, I now took only 3 minutes… :-D I'll try the other answer too now.

Comment: The join will get slower with more repeating ID's. The session var approach (@AlmaDo's answer) will always be faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  t.id1,  t.value,
row_number()  over (partition by t.id1 order by t.value ) counter
from test t;
```

I hope this will be useful:)

Comment: ^ I found that one already, but I have mysql (look at the tags).

Comment: This is nice query for `Oracle` and `SQL Server`.

Comment: well,probably it would be better to delete sql tag.in addition to,perhaps this link would be useful to find  equivalent solution in MySQL:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963818/row-number-equivalent-in-mysql-for-inserting

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work for you:

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[value]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [id] ORDER BY value) AS 'counter'
  FROM [TableName]
```

ROW_NUMBER will add the numbering.
The PARTITION BY clause allows us to group the results within the call to ROW_NUMBER() without grouping them ourselves via a GROUP BY. It just tells the ROW_NUMBERR what groupings to use when it does its counting.

For MySql you can use those links:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/09/mysql-reset-row-number-for-each-group-partition-by-row-number/

http://www.folkstalk.com/2013/03/grouped-row-number-function-mysql.html

In your case:

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SET @id:='';
SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @id=id THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS row_number , @id:=id AS id, value
FROM TableName
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Question is tagged `mysql`, isn't it?

Comment: This is wrong reason to answer with sql-server query because it's specific syntax which _won't work_ for mysql. So, despite it has linked to sql, it's still not correct to answer with non-working syntax for specific-tagged questions (in short: `mysql` overrides `sql`)