# sql - get row position as a result

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to figure out how to include a return for the row position in the result set.  It is a very simple table that is ordered by `computer_id` with a WHERE clause.  All I am looking for is something like `(*row position*) as position` in the results for each.

I found a few things by searching here on SO, but nothing I was able to get working.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT *
    FROM computers
    WHERE account_id = :account_id
    ORDER BY computer_id    
");

$stmt->bindValue( ':account_id', $_SESSION['user']['account_id'] );
$stmt->execute();   

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo '<pre>',print_r($results,1),'</pre>';
```

Comment: I guess you are asking for row number against each row returned by query ?

Comment: Would the auto incremented key field of this table not explicitly match your data row, or have you **gasp** done deletes and gotten your key vs row position out of sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want in one query (which the referenced duplicate question does not do):

```
SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) as rownumber, c.*
FROM computers c cross join
     (select @rn := 0) var
WHERE account_id = :account_id
ORDER BY computer_id;
```

To get a row number across all rows, use a subquery:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) as rownumber, c.*
      FROM computers c cross join
           (select @rn := 0) var
      ORDER BY computer_id
     ) c
WHERE account_id = :account_id;
```

Note that this will take more time, because it has to process the entire table.

Comment: This is working, but I am losing the correct order when ordering by other columns.  Is it possible to set the rownumber by computer_id as its own table where that reference will always be the correct rownumber? Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: The second option is working for me although the rownumber is off.  For instance, I have 10 entries in `computers`.. the first 6 belong to account_id = 1 and the last 4 belong to account_id = 2.  Showing for the second account is correct, but the rownumber starts at 7...8,9,10 instead of 1,2,3,4.  Ideas?

Comment: I was able to fix the problem I mentioned by moving the where clause into the select statement... it would not process the entire table this way either.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is PHP you could just create a variable, iterate through the results and increment the variable as you go.

There's also this: [ROW_NUMBER() equivalent in MySQL for inserting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963818/row-number-equivalent-in-mysql-for-inserting)

which gets you something similar to row_number() in MS SQL.

Comment: For this scenario I cannot do that.  I am using a third party script - DataTables.